# Is there a MySQL Equivalent of Dynamic Data Masking

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Long time reader, first time posting so apologies if anything doesn't confirm to the correct way.

I currently built a SaaS platform, with a MySQL database containing PPI. I want to expand the team and require them to access the database. However; theres' way too much PPI data to allow a new remote hire access to it all.

I came across Microsoft SQL Server's [Dynamic Data Masking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking?view=sql-server-ver15) function which was perfect until I realised it isn't available in MySQL. I can't find any similar function, does one exist? and if not any suggestions as to how I could achieve something similar to granting access whilst protecting my data

Thanks

Comment: You should use views.  Don't allow users direct access to any tables.  And only select safe columns for the views.

Comment: That wouldn't work as they need access to the information associated to the PPI data which is in multiple locations due to the way the software works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest thing in MySQL is column-level privileges.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html#grant-column-privileges

This combined with the support for roles (new in MySQL 8.0) should make it easier to create separate sets of column-level access privileges, granting those privileges to roles. When a new employee joins, grant them the role with limited access. Once they've been around long enough to be trusted, then grant them the additional role with the PII column privileges.